# Flex 4 Image Fill

Tags: image, flex4, flashbuilder4

I have a controls.Image that I put in my Flex4 AIR App.

I set it to x=0, y=0.
Width=100%, Height=100%.

The problem with this, is that The source image I am using does not fit the whole app screen. The actual controls.Image covers the entire screen, but the source image contained in the controls.Image does not fill the entire controls.Image height/width.

Is there any way to "fill" the entirety of the controls.Image with the source?
I am not worried about warping the source image, I would just like to fill the entire controls.Image no matter what the height/width of it are.

I cannot find the tool to do so.. anyone recommend tips? I cannot find anything related to "FillMode" or similar and have been searching for awhile now.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If by 'controls.Image', you mean `mx.controls.Image`, which is technically a Flex 3 component, but is applicable in Flex 4.1 and earlier, you want to set `maintainAspectRatio` to `false`, and make sure that `scaleContent` is `true` (which is the default value).

On the other hand, if you are using Flex 'Hero' SDK (Flex 4.5), which introduces a native spark image component (`spark.components.Image`), you'll need to set `scaleMode` to `BitmapScaleMode.STRETCH`, and make sure `fillMode` is set to `BitmapFillMode.SCALE` (which is the default value).

**AS3 Documentation:**

[mx.controls.Image (Flex 4.1 and earlier)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Image.html#propertySummary)

[spark.components.Image (Flex 4.5 "Hero")](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Image.html#scaleMode)

Answer (score 0):

All of these tips are assuming that the blank parts of the image are transparent.

-You could put your image in a BorderContainer, and set the background color of the container.

-You could create a bitmap of a certain width or height, then fill with a background color (bitmap.fill I believe). Then copy our image bitmap data onto that.

Personally,  I think the BorderContainer option is the easiest to get off the ground.